# Colorbox -- how to open submitted form in colorbox pop-up?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a form on a webpage. When the user enters input into form, and hits Submit, I would like colorbox to pop-up with the results page.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

I'm thinking that I have to convert the form data into a get string, put that on the end of the url to open, and then send that to colorbox. Is that the right way to go about it, or is there an easier way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To this, I would:

1. Manually submit the form by serializing the form as an array
2. Then, submit the data using `get`, `post`, or `ajax`.
3. Write the response to an invisible `div` and then use `colorbox` on this `div`.

**Example:**

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.get("mypage", formData, function(r){
        $("body").append("<div id='response'></div>");
        $("#response").hide().html(r).colorbox();
    });
    return false; // To override non-ajax submitting
});
```

Modifications you might have to make:

- Change `get` to `post` or `ajax`
- Change the `div` that the response gets dumped to (perhaps generate a div with a random ID instead of using a constant, `response`, as the ID)

Also:

> I'm thinking that I have to convert
>   the form data into a get string, put
>   that on the end of the url to open,
>   and then send that to colorbox.

This would work, but only if your form works with `get`. I wouldn't recommend using `get` for forms in general, as this can lead to nasty CSRF and XSS attacks.

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to apply colorbox. It says that the object doesn't support the method! Any ideas? It doesn't happen when I call colorbox outside of the call back handler.

Comment: Oh.. the content was loading in jquery again.